# How to parse integer value to Json iOS?

Tags: ios, json, parsing, uitableview

I was passed NSstring it is coming properly data into uitableview but when I am parsing integer value it showing exception  Terminating app due to uncaught exception `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: -[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x744e9d0`
This is my code

```
(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {  
//parse out the json data  
NSError* error;  
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization  
JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];  
  NSArray * values=[json objectForKey:@"loans"];  


 NSLog(@"Array: %@",values);

for (NSDictionary *file in values)
        {
            NSNumber *fileTitle=[file objectForKey:@"id"];
            // NSString *fileTitle = [file objectForKey:@"sector"];
            [titles addObject: fileTitle];
        }
[self.mainTableView reloadData];

 }
```

Comment: It's telling you what's wrong, if you only read the message.  Though the error is not in the above code.  You are attempting to treat an NSNumber as a string.  Numbers in JSON generally translate to Objective-C NSNumbers.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning string value to `NSNumber` type.
Try to use this

```
NSString *fileTitle=[file objectForKey:@"id"];

[titles addObject: fileTitle];
```

and use string value.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[titles addObject: fileTitle] stringValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are doing something like this in your `-tableView: cellForIndexPath`:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [...];
cell.titleLabel.text = titles[indexPath.row];
```

You can only use NSString for `-[UILabel setText:]` method.

Convert your NSNumber to NSString with a simple `-[NSNumber stringValue]` or using NSNumberFormatter.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems ok. Just replace

```
NSNumber *fileTitle=[file objectForKey:@"id"];
```

by `NSString *fileTitle = [file objectForKey:@"id"];`